# SQL Server Updating the database through a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

We have a 3rd party application that takes a SQL select statement and runs it against a SQL Server database at a regular scheduled interval. It wakes up regularly, runs the select for input and does it's thing. The issue is we really need it to run the select statement then update a column for the rows it selected.

Idea 1:
Create a stored procedure that would do the updated and return the data and have the app call that.
Fail -- It looks like you can't call a stored procedure from a select statement

Idea 2:
Create a User Defined Function, which can be called in a select.
Fail -- Can't perform an update from a User Defined Function.

Idea 3:
Use the `OPENQUERY(...)` function to perform the select.
Fail -- I don't have permissions to create a linked server.

Any other ideas?

NOTE: The application required that the statement you give it starts with `select` .

Comment: Where do the results of the `select` go?  Would using `select ... into ...` be a first step?

Comment: Would be great if there were a `SELECT` trigger, wouldn't it? Unfortunately, [it's been requested and denied](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/212165/growing-need-for-a-select-trigger).

Comment: How, exactly, does the application pass the select statement to the database? Perhaps there is a way you can fool it by naming your stored procedure `SELECT<something>`...

Comment: @Stinky . . . Perhaps a crazy idea.  Use `select into` some table name and create a DML trigger that checks for that table being created.

Comment: Since it's running at a regularly scheduled interval, could you create a job that also runs at a regularly scheduled interval that populates a work table that the 3rd party's `SELECT` will run against? So long as you're scheduled to run before it does (and with suitable locking hints) you can ensure that its select doesn't run until you've populated exactly what you want. (For bonus points, you can also run a server trace that detects the `SELECT` being run and clears the work table once its complete

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hmm... This might be brilliant. I'll try it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I assume the query can be different between runs (perhaps the users input different runtime parameters occasionally), otherwise it should be pretty easy to tell what rows were selected at any point in time if the query is always the same. But if not, that solution makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I set the query once and this same query is run over and over. Previously we were using GETDATE() in the select against a DATE_INSERTED field, so that each time it ran it picked up the rows for that day (so same query, different results each day).

Comment: We just made sure all the requests were inserted before this 3rd party app was scheduled to run and we could be sure all the requests were picked up for the day. Our BA now wants to run it once per minute. It would be way too error prone to try to sync up inserting of requests early in the minute and count on the 3rd party app to run later in the minute. So now we need a way to record what was selected.